# How to find total number of pages in a site and count of words in SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, site-collection, analytics

I am requested to generate a report that illustrates the number of pages and their corresponding URLs, plus the count of words on a page, and the number of files in that site (word, PDF, images..etc.).

is there any custom tool that i can use to enter my SharePoint site URL and then it will generate me the report i'm looking for ?

Or if you think SharePoint shell commands can help with this, please share your ideas with me.

Many Thanks.

Comment: SharePoint 2013 or 2010??

Comment: Thank you for your response, SP 2010 and 2013, or any of them.

Comment: There is Sharepoint hidden list named **Site Pages** it contains all the site pages information. Which you expecting regard pages.